# Bold first word in title field

Tags: redactor, markdown

Site design I am working on the first word of ever page title is bold. The code looks like this;

```
<h1 class="section__heading"><strong>Discover</strong> Riaflex Today</h1>
```

I am struggling to find a simple solution to do this in Craft.

If I setup a simple rich text field then it wraps "p" tags around it. I have tried to used Markdown but this is the same and also end up with ** in the <'title'> output.

Anyone done something similar or can offer a fairly simple approach. I had a quick  attempt at editing radactor but dropped it as it didn't seem to work and remove 'p' tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple text field?

Comment: Do you mean a plain text field? If you do then this is because it won't allow the user to bold the first word.

Comment: Yep. How about a separate plain text field for the title and then a rich text field for the rest?

Comment: The problem is that the title needs to have the first word bold.

Comment: Ah. now I get it.

Comment: @KSPR's answer is correct. Here is a working demo... http://twigfiddle.com/j3hfyu

Comment: Nice :) can you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: @Fyrebase, I moved your answer to a comment since it was a comment. (Just an FYI.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grab the first word with the split filter according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281925/twig-how-to-get-the-first-word-of-a-string)

```
{% set array = entry.title|split(' ', 2) %}
<h1 class="section__heading">
   <strong>{{ attribute(array, 0) }}</strong>
   {{ attribute(array, 1) }}
</h1>
```

I didn't test this tough.

Edit: there is a [Twig Fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/j3hfyu) demonstrating it.

Comment: Yes thanks KSPR. I found that solution shortly before you posted. Seems to work well.